# Openlayers XYZ tiles loaded even when visibility is false

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I'm adding a XYZ layer in OL6 like:

```
      const saarland = new ol.layer.Tile({
        title: 'testLayer',
        visible: false,
        source: new ol.source.XYZ({
          params: {
            transparent: true,
            format: 'image/png',
          },
          minZoom: 10,
          url:
            'https://tiles.domain.com/EPSG_900913/{z}/{x}/{y}.png' +
            '?apikey=mykey',
          }
        )
      })
```

But even if the layer is hidden tiles are requested that do not exist in this extent ending in hundreds of 404. To solve this my idea was to explicitly hide the layer above a certain zoom level:

```
      function changeVisibility(l_name, vis) {
          var layer_name = l_name;
          map.getLayers().forEach(function(lyr) {
              if (lyr.get('title') === layer_name) {
                lyr.setVisible(vis);
              }
          });
      }

      var currZoom = map.getView().getZoom();
      map.on('moveend', function(e) {
        var newZoom = map.getView().getZoom();
        if (currZoom != newZoom) {
          currZoom = newZoom;
          if (newZoom >= 10) {
            changeVisibility('testLayer', true)
          } else {
            changeVisibility('testLayer', false)
          }
        }
      });
```

Again this shows/hides the layer, but unfortuantely this does not prevent tiles beeing requested on Zoom level < 10.

How can I prevent Openayers requesting tiles if the layer is hidden?

Comment: It doesn't happen when I try it https://codesandbox.io/s/xyz-esri-forked-zwx0oy?file=/main.js  Do you have anything else in your code such as a layer switcher which might be changing the visibility?

Comment: good point. yes I'm using a layer switch. let me try to kick it out for a second to see if it causes it.